# Trying to use Google Map Javascript API but getting a QuotaService.RecordEvent request URL blocked

Tags: google-maps

Trying to use the Google Map Javascript API.

I have the 3 things on the page which I believe are required to display a map.

The script tag in the header:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=APIKEY&map_ids=MAPID&callback=initMap"
   async>
</script>
```

The div tag with an id of map:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Create a new map in js:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
zoom: 8,
mapId: 'MAPID' });
```

But when the page loads a request URL that is getting blocked. Blocked URL is:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/QuotaService.RecordEvent?1shttp://127.0.0.1...APIKEY...
```

Been googling 'QuotaService.RecordEvent google maps blocked' but I haven't been able to find a solution.

The API is attached to a project that has billing enabled.

Any idea why it is getting blocked? I'm sure I did something wrong, but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 5):

Found what was causing the URL to be blocked.

[uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en)

I turned it off and the URL is no longer blocked. Which is weird since a lot of people use uBlock. I'm a Google Maps API rookie so I will figure it out but the URL is no longer blocked. :)

Comment: I was getting the same error in Brave so switched to Chrome.